# Custom colors of commandbutton in userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have succesfully colored the font and background of one button (commandbutton_1) in my userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(225, 225, 225)
    UserForm.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
End Sub
```

But when I apply the same code to my second button (CommandButton2), it is not working properly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm2_Activate()
    CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = RGB(225, 225, 225)
    UserForm.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would only work if the second command button were in a userform called `UserForm2` as thats whats in your event handlers: `UserForm2_MouseMove`

Consolidate the code in to the event of the form you have called `UserForm`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    CommandButton2.BackColor = CommandButton1.BackColor
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = CommandButton1.ForeColor
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

With help from @Alex K., I found the answer to be:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    CommandButton2.BackColor = CommandButton1.BackColor
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = CommandButton1.ForeColor
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(225, 225, 225)

    CommandButton2.BackColor = CommandButton1.BackColor
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = CommandButton1.ForeColor

    UserForm.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() , here you can have all your formats for all CommandButtons, Labels, Textboxes etc. that you are using in your Userform :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton1.ForeColor = RGB(225, 225, 225)
    UserForm.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)

    CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(22, 54, 92)
    CommandButton2.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
```